# File is universal (three slices), but it does not contain a(n) ARMv7-s slice error for static libraries on iOS, anyway to bypass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, static-libraries

I upgraded [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) version and when using external static libraries, I get this message:

> ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /file/location for architecture armv7s
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Is there any way to bypass this and add support to the library if the developer of the library hasn't updated their library yet?

Comment: This seems to be a good solution for now - http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/09/hacking-up-an-armv7s-library/

Answer (score 419, accepted):

If you want to remove the support for any architecture, for example, [ARMv7-s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#ARM_cores) in your case, use menu *Project* -> *Build Settings* -> remove the architecture from "valid architectures".

You can use this as a temporary solution until the library has been updated. You have to remove the architecture from your main project, not from the library.

Alternatively, you can set the flag for your debug configuration's "Build Active Architecture Only" to Yes. Leave the release configuration's "Build Active Architecture Only" to No, just so you'll get a reminder before releasing that you ought to upgrade any third-party libraries you're using.

Comment: nice solution but is there a way to add support without compiling the library ?

Comment: you don't have to recompile the library. you can remove this flag from the project that is using the library.

Comment: I guess that the app will not work on the iPhone 5 then, am I right ?

Comment: It will work, since old apps that have not been compiled with armv7s support have to run as well. But you will loose some specific optimizations.
This should be a temporary workaround anyway.

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? Or is there something else I need to do? I have both Architectures and Valid Architectures set to armv7 but still have this problem.

Comment: Dropbox framework has been updated for this issue see https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=90014

Comment: For some projects, the problem might be the Architectures setting, and not the valid architectures setting. The meaning of $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT), despite being labeled as "Standard (armv7)" now appears to include armv7s also. Removing $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) in favor of an explicit armv7 did the trick for me.

Comment: Removing armv7s from the Valid Architectures list worked for me, however so did removing it from Architectures. In both cases, however, I would get `No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386, VALID_ARCHS=armv7).` from the linker which I could only solve by adding `i386` to the Valid Architectures list.

Comment: My project only supports armv7 and armv7s (not armv6) as 'valid architectures', yet getting this error when building for Device in SDK 6. (Using libOAuth.a)

Comment: Oh, sorry; didn't read all the comments before commenting. I too removed armv7 **s** and now it's working

Comment: What is 'armv7s' anyway? Nothing to do with the iPhone 4S I guess? ;)

Comment: No, armv7s is the instruction set of the A6 processor that is being used in the iPhone 5. Since the A6 is backwards compatible, it will still run the armv7 instruction set.

Comment: thank for this answer, but i don't understand i have to remove the armv7s only in the setting of the static library, or also for the Main Project Target?

Comment: but theres only one flag in my project. not sure whether they r for build or for release

Comment: I just set Build Active Architecture Only" to Yes . Now my project is running successfully.

Comment: for me I had to remove armv7s and set "Build Active Architecture Only" to No and it worked.

Answer (score 190):

I've simply toggled "Build Active Architecture Only" to "Yes" in the target's build settings, and it's OK now!

Comment: @Blasco73
Do you even know that you are awesome? You should. Here goes, You sir, are awesome!

Comment: How can this be a good solution. It removes the error, but you only get build for the current arch, not all on the market...

Answer (score 27):

Try to remove armv7s from project's "Valid architecture" to release from this issue for iOS 5.1 phone

Answer (score 13):

I just posted a fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12412222/526433) that would also apply in this case - basically, you do a hex find-and-replace in your external library to make it think that it's ARMv7s code. You should be able to use `lipo` to break it into 3 static libraries, duplicate / modify the ARMv7 one, then use `lipo` again to assemble a new library for all 4 architectures.

Answer (score 5):

Flurry Support for iPhone 5 (ARMv7s)
As I mentioned in yesterday’s post, Flurry started working on a version of the iOS SDK to support the ARMv7s processor in the new iPhone 5 immediately after the announcement on Wednesday.

I am happy to tell you that the work is done and the SDK is now available on the site.

Answer (score 4):

use menu Project -> Build Settings ->

then remove armv7s from the"valid architectures".
If standard has been chosen then delete that and then add armv7.

Answer (score 1):

In case this happens to someone. I built my own library to use with a third party code. While I was building it to deliver, I accidentally left my iPhone 4S plugged in, and so Xcode built my library only for the plugged architecture instead of following the project settings. Remove any plugged in devices and rebuilt the library, link it, and you should be all right.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was linking to a third-party library that was a bit old (developed for iOS 6, on XCode 5 / iOS 7).  Therefore, I had to update the third-party library, do a Clean and Build, and it now builds successfully.