# Apple Mach-O Linker Error armv7s & libGoogleAdMobAds.a

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, armv7

I've just upgraded my app to run on the new iPhone5 simulator, however when I try to build it for my iPhone 4S device, I get this Apple Mach-O Liner error.

> ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s
>   slice: /Users/Darren/Documents/Dev stuff/My
>   App/GoogleAdMobAdsSDKiOS-5.0.5/libGoogleAdMobAds.a for architecture
>   armv7s clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

Can someone shed some light on what this error it and how to fix it?
I am using adWhirl with AdMob.

Thanks

EDIT ---
I am also getting this error in another project for the file libfacebook_ios_sdk.a

Comment: What's your `Deployment Target`?

Comment: I've just looked at another of my apps, and it has the same error when building for device.

Comment: I've just started editing a third, and this time get the error for libfacebook_ios_sdk.a

Comment: This question talks about information that is still under the NDA that you signed (which you broke by posting here), so please try the apple developer forums instead.

Comment: The iPhone 5 became public knowledge last night so I'm not sure which part of my question breaks the NDA

Comment: I got this working now. But I guess I can't say how.

Comment: The part about Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6 SDK, which are clearly still under NDA in bold letters when you log into your developer account.

Comment: I found the answer here: [Is there a compiler flag to indicate lack of armv7s architecture][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405378/is-there-a-compiler-flag-to-indicate-lack-of-armv7s-architecture

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The same answer as I gave in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402092/file-is-universal-3-slices-but-does-not-contain-an-armv7s-slice-error-for-st):

If you want to remove the support for any architecture, try this:

Project -> Build Settings -> remove the architecture from "valid architectures"

You can use this as a temporary solution until the library has been updated. You have to remove the flag from your own project.

Answer (score 2):

iPhone5's cpu is A6(armv7s).
The existing Admob sdk does not support it.
We have to wait for admob to update the sdk.

Comment: Their new sdk wont work with AdWhirl, so we either have to move to AdMob mediation, drop AdMob or stick with AdWhirl & AdMob but remove armv7s support from the build.

Comment: The admob page says it's not compatible with AdWhirl http://cl.ly/image/1u2b2F1M0P1p

Comment: @Darren, that says you can not use admob sdk as an AdSense SDK in Adwhirl

Comment: This is the google group thread for news about it, for the moment still nothing. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/9Wub-gh9rf8

Answer (score 2):

Update to Admob 6.2.0 or later.

See this post: http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/09/migrating-to-admob-v62-for-ios.html.

Also, include the AdSupport framework and remove the -all_load flag. 
You've got to use the -ObjC flag however.

This works for me, finally!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This article copy an armv7 lib code as an armv7s and build into the original lib. so xcode will see that lib has an armv7s code/arch

http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/09/hacking-up-an-armv7s-library/