# XCode won't compile - file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice

Tags: xcode, compilation, clang, armv7

I am trying to compile my app on XCode for armv7s and armv7, but keep getting this error.

I've tried compiling with armv6 included and again no luck.  Any ideas anybody?  I'm completely stumped.

```
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/User/Documents/App/AdMob/libGoogleAdMobAds.a for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apple Mach-O Linker Error armv7s & libGoogleAdMobAds.a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403630/apple-mach-o-linker-error-armv7s-libgoogleadmobads-a)

Comment: @MartinR - not duplicate - a forgotten flag - see below!

Answer (score 0):

Oops - figured it out - was compiling for armv7 and armv7s and had removed '-all_load' from linker flags!