# linker command failed with exit code 1 xcode4.5

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I updated my iphone4s and xcode to the latest yesterday. And I'm trying to debug my app on my phone since my application uses hardware communication. 
I'm using a third party library from Redpark(the company provides Dock to RS232 wire.)
While compiling, it gives an error

```
ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice:/Users/...../libRscMgrUniv.a for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this except waiting for Redpark to update there library?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply disable the compilation of `armv7s` in your Build Settings, by replacing the `$VALID_ARCHITECTURES` (which evaluates to `armv7 armv7s` now) value by the explicit value `armv7`.

Thus your application will only build for `armv7` and not `armv7s`, so will not be fully optimized for the new iPhone5, but it will still run on iPhone 4 and 5 anyway (the `armv7s` processor of the iPhone 5 can execute `armv7` applications, it is just not as optimized as with `armv7s` processor dedicated instructions)

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, it works. I also found that by changing BUILD ACTIVE ARCHITECTURE ONLY to NO works too.

Comment: If this solves your question, don't forget to tick the checkmark near my answer to mark your question as solved for other visitors.

Answer (score 3):

I did another search and found two solutions work for me.
[Dafna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402092/file-is-universal-3-slices-but-does-not-contain-an-armv7s-slice-error-for-st)
1. Go to Target Setting -> Build Settings -> Build Active Architecture Only -> change to NO.
2. Still in Build Settings -> Valid Architecture -> delete armv7s.

They both work for me. If you have the same problem, definitely try this first.