# Mach O Link Error- linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, twitter, archive

When I try building for archiving for my app in Xcode (version 4.5) I get an error that says:

```
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/[myrealname]/Downloads/[myappname]/BT_Objects/TwitterOAuth/SAOAuthTwitterEngine/libOAuth.a for architecture armv7s
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
It then says under it:

```
(null): File is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/shakerite/Downloads/shakeritetestnotrealone_v15_iOS/BT_Objects/TwitterOAuth/SAOAuthTwitterEngine/libOAuth.a for architecture armv7s
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice error for static libraries on iOS, anyway to bypass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402092/file-is-universal-3-slices-but-does-not-contain-an-armv7s-slice-error-for-st)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I received a very similar message just the other day when I tried running my app on my iPad after several successful attempts on the simulator.  I found out that under the build settings I had to make "build active architecture only" to yes.  Then my app would compile on my device. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Douglas, I don't see where it says "build active architecture only." Is it under build settings for the target or the project?

Comment: @shak77, the Build Active Architecture Only is under targets and then build settings.  However, you do need to pick All instead of Basic!  It is at the top of the build setting pane on the left.

Comment: @shak77,  glad to hear.  Don't forget to accept the answer, so the question will be closed!  I am glad that I could help.

Comment: Thanks.....a lot..i got similar Error.....but thanks to @Douglas...Really Much Helpful..and saved my lot of hours..+1 from my side for this

Comment: This works! Anyway if you do not have separate build targets for different devices, it wold be wise to change in the project settings rather than target settings

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I had this same exact problem. Click on your project in xcode. Then, click on the target. Go to build settings and look for valid architectures. Delete armv7s from the list of valid architectures and just leave armv7.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I'll make sure to try this when I get on my computer with the app. Thanks so much.

Comment: Make sure your changing 'Valid Architectures' and not 'Architectures'

Comment: @ttarules,  This is Douglas.  I just wanted to one up you, because I just got a new device and got the Mach O error.  So I followed my answer and got no where.  So I tried yours out and it worked great.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

here I provide you one temporary solution that can solve this error hope its help you,

> go to Project->Build Settings->Build Active Architecture Only->yes

thats it.

Comment: -1 : your solution is a duplicate of what @Douglas has posted an year ago.