# Apple Mach-O Linker error for only one device. Other phone works fine

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

Xcode is giving me an error when I'm trying to test my app on my iPhone 5. It works perfectly on the iPhone 6 plus. Both are running the same OS and are registered to my developer account.

The specific error is: "can't link with a main executable file" from my derived data folder "for architecture armv7".

I tried updating the last version of X-Code 6, restarting, and cleaning the file with no success.

Any ideas?

[image: error]

[image: screenshot]

Edit:
I found this suggestion: [can't link with a main executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031932/cant-link-with-a-main-executable-file). 
When I selected a app name, I now get this error.
[image]

Comment: Could you add more information. Perhaps a larger extract of the error log?

Comment: Sure thing. Added a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Looks like an architecture error. In your target's build settings, make sure under `Architectures` and `Valid Architectures` both `armv7` and `arm64` are included. iPhone 5 has a 32-bit processor, and iPhone 5s and on have 64-bit

Comment: I did have armv7 and arm64 for Valid Architectures as a default. I should mention that this ran perfectly fine until I changed the bundle ID, App ID, and provisioning profiles. But again, it runs fine on the iphone 6.

Comment: Try these solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591711/mach-o-link-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocat  Please give me a +1 if it helps.