# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1, Xcode Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, linker-errors

I am getting this error when I try to Build the app or even try to run in on a real phone or do Product > Archive.

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/mycomputer/Google Drive/PROJECTS/MyProject/code/MyProject/build/Debug-iphoneos'
>
> ld: framework not found Charts
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

These are the things I have tried already (no change of course):

- Re-run `pod install` again and re-opened the workspace file.
- Did Clean (clean succeeded) and then try to run `Archive` again.
- Set `build active architecture only` to Yes ([this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591711/mach-o-link-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocat))
- Removed pod project completely and ran `pod install` again
- I even removed `pod 'SwiftCharts', '~> 0.3'` from the PodFile and its use from the project, but still the error message is the same.

The error messages says:

> ld: framework not found Charts

but my `PodFile` does have this: `pod 'SwiftCharts', '~> 0.3'`

This is my *PodFile*:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, “9.0”

use_frameworks!
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseUI'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
pod 'SwiftCharts', '~> 0.3'


target 'ShitTalk' do

end

target 'ShitTalkTests' do

end

target 'ShitTalkUITests' do

end
```

What else can I try?

Comment: Are you using Swift 1.2 or 2.0?

Comment: Swift 2.0, and XCode 7

Comment: -framework "SwiftCharts" is added to the Other Linker Flags?

Comment: @ridvankucuk - Yes, I believe so. Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2o0uoqhdmesuhkg/Screenshot%202015-10-22%2002.05.39.png?dl=0

Comment: I have tried to add "SwiftCharts" to a new project and it works. I believe that you don't write unittest. If not i suggest you to remove DerivedData.

Comment: So I deleted the folder DerivedData and reopened the project, still no luck. Did I do it right? No, I have not written any tests.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was I defined a const in a header file:

**ClassA.h:**

```
NSString * const kDriveCameraVideoFlenameExtension = @"mp4";
```

Then, when I imported this header file

**ClassB.m:**

```
#import ClassA.h
```

The linker crashed with this error.
Luckily I'm old enough to know some C. To solve this issue all I had to do is change the scope of the constant by making it static:

```
static NSString * const kDriveCameraVideoFlenameExtension = @"mp4";
```

Problem gone, as now the constant belongs to the class and not to the global scope.