# After update xcode, an old app that works no longer builts, and it's reporting this error that I have no idea what it is.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/TianLongWang/iOSDeveloper/OpenTok/newhelloworld/OpenTok-iOS-Hello-World/Opentok.framework/Opentok for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Try searching...this question has already been asked many times.  For example -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402092/file-is-universal-3-slices-but-does-not-contain-an-armv7s-slice-error-for-st

Answer (score 1):

I received a very similar message just the other day when I tried running my app on my iPad after several successful attempts on the simulator. I found out that under the build settings I had to make "build active architecture only" to yes. Then my app would compile on my device. Hope this helps.  Make sure when you select build settings you select "all" to show everything.