# Rubymotion removing armv7 from compilation settings

Tags: testflight, rubymotion

In a project I am using testflight. When using the project in the simulator it works fine. 
But when I deploy the project to the iPhone I get the error:

```
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice:  
Path/TestFlightSDK/libTestFlight.a for architecture armv7s
```

In this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402092/file-is-universal-3-slices-but-does-not-contain-an-armv7s-slice-error-for-st) I can find the solution when using Xcode. Basically removing compatibility for armv7, because Testflight is not compiled for it.

How do I add this setting to Rubymotion? Do I need to add something to the rakefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. Download the new SDK from TestFlight (Version 1.1) add a reference to this version of the libTestFlight.a and TestFlight.h to your project or copy these two files to your project.
Afterwards add the libTestFlight.a into your linked Frameworks and Libraries.
Perform a clean build. Afterwards it worked for me!

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Apparently something was cached somewhere.