# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) (armv7) xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode4, barcode-scanner, armv7

I tried to compile my xcode project (i use xcode 4.5) and i have installed cordova 1,5 and the plugin BarecodeScanner on my project.

When i try to compile on iOs 6 ipod devices, i have the following error :

```
Ld "/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codebarre4-dfyfuljrumiqgvbcbcsmwxzxbnuq/Build/Intermediates/codebarre4.build/Ad Hoc Distribution-iphoneos/codebarre4.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/codebarre4" normal armv7s
    cd /Users/username/Sites/iOS/codebarre4
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk "-L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codebarre4-dfyfuljrumiqgvbcbcsmwxzxbnuq/Build/Products/Ad Hoc Distribution-iphoneos" "-F/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codebarre4-dfyfuljrumiqgvbcbcsmwxzxbnuq/Build/Products/Ad Hoc Distribution-iphoneos" -F/Users/Shared/Cordova/Frameworks -filelist "/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codebarre4-dfyfuljrumiqgvbcbcsmwxzxbnuq/Build/Intermediates/codebarre4.build/Ad Hoc Distribution-iphoneos/codebarre4.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/codebarre4.LinkFileList" -dead_strip -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -weak-liconv -weak_framework CoreVideo -weak_framework AssetsLibrary -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreLocation -framework MediaPlayer -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreMedia -framework Cordova -o "/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codebarre4-dfyfuljrumiqgvbcbcsmwxzxbnuq/Build/Intermediates/codebarre4.build/Ad Hoc Distribution-iphoneos/codebarre4.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/codebarre4"

ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/Shared/Cordova/Frameworks/Cordova.framework/Cordova for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This error message is very complicated to understand... i searched on the web but found anything... Have you got any idea of the origin of this message ?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me, was to set "Enable Bitcode" to "No" in the Build Settings > Build options.

Use the search on the top: http://screencast.com/t/xSCnqHGkhh

The error I was getting was:

> XXX does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled
>   (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the
>   vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64

Answer (score 0):

Your project may be configured to target armv7 which is hindering the linker.

1. Select your project
2. Go to info tab
3. Remove Required Device Capability item if existing (may be armv7 called)

Comment: i'll dig some more later, if I find anything i'll get back here with a reply

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error as well.

I resolved the issue on my end by using the following steps:

1. Going to the `Build Settings` for the Project.
2. Under the `Settings` > `Valid Architecture settings`, I had the values for Debug set to `armv7` and `armv7s`.  And I had the values for Release set to `armv7` and `armv7s`.
3. I realized that the `armv7s` items were causing the problem.  So I removed `armv7s` from both entries.

After that, I was able to archive my project with no issues.

Comment: Does this end up making your app runnable on all previously-supported devices?

Answer (score 0):

You might not have included any framework in your project. Go to

> Project > targets > build phases > link binary with libraries

and add your missing framework.

Answer (score 0):

Also see [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402092/file-is-universal-three-slices-but-it-does-not-contain-an-armv7-s-slice-err).

1. Make sure your Build Settings "Architectures" setting includes the target architecture (the processor chip) - armv7 for iOS 6, armv7s for iOS 7, etc.
2. If you have any third party libraries you link in, make sure they are built with the proper architecture support.  Otherwise rebuild those libraries or check the developer for update downloads.
3. Finally, reopen the project with updated libraries, Clean, and Build.
4. You may also want to verify you have an up-to-date XCode with the right iOS supporting environments.