# New iOS SDK Best Practices

Tags: iphone, ios

Every iOS SDK release I skip all the beta releases simply because I never wanted to mess up my current software/SDK versions. I wanted to make sure xCode still worked fine for my current projects but I could still get a "BETA" version.

What is the best way to download the newest SDK's without messing up your existing versions?

Comment: The new SDK is under NDA and your are not allowed to talk about it outside of the official Apple developers forum.

Comment: You can install multiple versions of xCode, I have done so before and I did not experience any "messing up" as you described above

Comment: @rckoenes, yes however asking if installing a new beta of XCode would conflict any existing XCode builds is not specific to iOS 7 and nothing would be considered outside the NDA.

Comment: @rckoenes I think that logixologist talks about beta versions __in general__. Nothing specific to iOS 7 here.

Comment: @logixologist this is true. But still talking about the new Xcode or SDK is not allowed by the NDA.

Comment: @rckoenes please refrain from talking about the <youKnowWhat>. You do realise you have been talking about it, don't you? ;)

Comment: @IanClay totally wright ;) but I have not named the <youKownWhat) :P

Comment: I have no clue what you guys are talking about ;) (thank you Stack Overflow editing!!!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is none. Installing a new version of Xcode might mess up with your settings. Also, a project created in `Xcode N+1` (or updated with it) might not be openable in `Xcode N`.

For `iOS N+1`, it's even worse: Apple says that you can't roll back to `iOS N` after installing the beta. It used to work for my colleagues with `iOS 6 -> iOS 5` though.

The only thing I can think of:

- Install Xcode N+1 on another mac
- Install iOS N+1 on another phone.

Comment: Will it actually create a new application that can be run seperate from the old XCode.

Comment: developer previews are title Xcode-DP so you can install them next to each other

Answer (score 1):

Just run multiple versions of Xcode on your machine. This has been straightforward since it became a self contained dmg package available on the App Store.

See my answer below for more information:

[Can I deploy an iOS 5.1 SDK app to a device running iOS 6.0 from Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705103/can-i-deploy-an-ios-5-1-sdk-app-to-a-device-running-ios-6-0-from-xcode/12705358#12705358)