# Implement new Google Maps SDK to my iOS app

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

UPDATE: I've just received an email from Google about the new Google Maps iOS SDK. Seems that everything has sorted out. I have successfully create new API key for my app! Didn't sully test it yet, but seems correct. They sent me [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#the_google_maps_api_key) URL page.

### Good Luck!

---

I am trying from yesterday to change my code so be able to use the new Google Maps SDK that released 2 days ago. I have follow all the instructions but until now didn't achieve to display them.
I have already request for an API key but without any reply until now. In addition I am trying to get an API key from [the Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) but in list of Services I can't find *"Google Maps SDK for iOS"*.

Secondly, when I am trying to run my app(on Simulator), screen is black, I can see just Google logo on the left-hand side (and press it as well). I am getting these messages on Log screen:

```
2012-12-14 12:20:57.132 CoL[515:7a03] Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.0.1.1154
2012-12-14 12:20:57.132 CoL[515:7a03] New version of Google Maps SDK for iOS available: 1.0.1.1154
2012-12-14 12:20:57.192 CoL[515:c07] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-14 12:20:57.242 CoL[515:c07] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-14 12:21:01.291 CoL[515:c07] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-14 12:21:09.314 CoL[515:c07] ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-14 12:21:13.339 CoL[515:c07] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-14 12:21:13.363 CoL[515:c07] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
2012-12-14 12:21:17.386 CoL[515:c07] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining. Error Domain=DASHConnectionError Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DASHConnectionError error 100.)"
```

**UPDATE:** Just noticed that project can't be built successfully on device (iPhone 4S, iOS 6). I don't know if that related with my problem above but here is the error:

```
ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/.../GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and how my Architectures section looks like
[image]

Anyone who has achieved to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an API key to use the new google maps SDK. This is what mentioned in [their page](https://developers.google.com/maps/ios-access).

> Thanks for your interest in the Google Maps SDK for iOS. Currently
>   we're taking applications for access for an API Key. Please provide
>   details about your app below. **We'll mail successful applicants when a
>   key becomes available.**

So you have to wait till the keys are available.

Check [this google maps start page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start). You can register your project there and it will be available.

For the second issue, check this [File is universal (three slices), but it does not contain a(n) ARMv7-s slice error for static libraries on iOS, anyway to bypass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402092/file-is-universal-3-slices-but-does-not-contain-an-armv7s-slice-error-for-st). You might have to remove the support for armv7s from your project.

Comment: Still didn't receive any e-mail. Do you know how long it takes to receive an API key? Thanks for information.

Comment: @PanayiotisNicolaou, Updated my answer with a link. Go to this page and create API project here, https://code.google.com/apis/console/. If this helped, can you please accept it.

Comment: I have already visited this page but in Services list I can't find any (service) called/described as "Google Maps SDK for iOS". There are 55 Services in total. I've just filled the API key form. Why I can't see that Service?

Comment: @PanayiotisNicolaou, I think then they haven't included that there. We might have to wait for the API key then..

Comment: How they can giving instructions about how to obtain an API key, when they don't include that Service? Can't understand.

Comment: @PanayiotisNicolaou, Yes, I can understand. So if this answers your question, can you please accept it. I am sure there is nothing else can be added to improve this answer further as long as google wont provide the API Keys.

Comment: Still didn't get it. If is not available yet, then how others are talking about this and have implemented apps? Thank you anyway

Comment: @PanayiotisNicolaou, Thanks. I will update this, if I get any other information. I haven't seen any apps using this framework though.

Comment: @PanayiotisNicolaou please share if you find any solution

Answer (score 8):

I have the real answer. So I received access to the SDK as well but it still wasn't working for me. It was showing up as a gray map with a pin on it.

Steps to fix:

Clean your Xcode project.
Reset iOS simulator.
Close Xcode and simulator.
Start up and run.

Obviously make sure you have your api in there, else it wont work at all.

Comment: this is the real answer

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it took four days before I receive activation of my API key for iOS.

After you receive the email from Google, visit again the API Services page, at that time you should be able to see **Google Maps SDK for iOS** in the list of API Services, then you can now use your given API key for iOS on your project.

Add this code on your `AppDelegate` 's method `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your project :

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR_API_KEY"];
```

Comment: Make sure that Google Maps SDK for iOS is turned on in the console.  This was my problem.  Derp.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue and my problem was that the bundle identifier I used to generate key in Google was different with the one I used in Xcode. On correcting the identifier, I got the issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your `API Key` is valid. Bundle identifier with which you created the `API Key` should be correct. Put the `API Key` in

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR_API_KEY"];
```

This will  help.

Answer (score 0):

This fail has been occurred due to failing of API key.
You have to first create a project with your project name and bundle identifier from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) .
Then enable Google Maps Directions API , Google Maps SDK for iOS  and others as required.
[image: Screen shot]
Then copy the api key and use as : [GoogleMaps without CocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782277/googlemaps-without-cocoapods/37672868#37672868)

Answer (score 0):

Steps to check -

1. Provide API Key, If you have no API Key, generate one selecting your project from Google API Console Log.
2. Check Required Framework -

   ```
   -CoreBluetooth.framework
   -OpenGLES.framework
   -ImageIO.framework
   -CoreData.framework
   -CoreText.framework
   -QuartzCore.framework
   -SystemConfiguration.framework
   -GLKit.framework
   -CoreLocation.framework
   -Security.framework
   -Accelerate.framework
   -libc++abi.tbd
   -libc++.1.tbd
   -libc.tbd
   -libicucore.tbd
   ```

3.Check Linker Flags - Add "-ObjC" & "$(inherited)" if not added already

4.Check Architecture - Add "$(ARCHS_STANDARD)" e.g(arm7, arm64) if not added already

5.Check if bundle is present on Copy Bundle Resources.

Do give your feedback if can run successfully. I want to know about the map performance in iPhone 4s because iPhone 4s has older OpenGL version so frame rate may become low and can cause map freeze sometimes.

Hope This helps, Thanks........ :)