# IOS - ObjC Google Maps Api Key

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

i just did everything right as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#adding_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios_to_your_project) but Xcode still gives that error:

```
  Google Maps SDK for iOS cannot connect or validate APIKey: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x8416b20 {data=<CFData 0x9187710 [0x27424d8]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}
2013-09-01 15:04:04.902 MyApp[1357:12e03] Your key may be invalid for your bundle ID: MyBundleID
```

So i 've googled it and got these: [first result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007075/google-maps-not-working-on-iphone-simulator),   [second result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878905/implement-new-google-maps-sdk-to-my-ios-app),  and it started to be boring from now on. Is there a way to make this mail thing faster, or am i doing wrong something still ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ohh, i've got the answer. Maybe someone needs it. Just clean {} these signs from your API KEY, i mean it shouldn't be like below

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"{123123123}"];
```

it should be like :

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"123123123"];
```

Answer (score 4):

Two things I would suggest double checking:

1. Be aware that the Bundle Identifier is case sensitive. If the capitalization is off in the application, or within the google development console, it will through this error.

   - Extra tip.. you can double check your application's bundle identifier by including a log similar to the following in your viewDidLoad method.

   ```
   NSLog(@"Current identifier: %@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]);
   ```
2. Make sure you've included the API key in your applications delegate as listed by Sercan Ozdemir above. Your App's delegate file should contain a method similar to the one below.

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
   {
       // Override point for customization after application launch.
       [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"INSERT_GOOGLE_API_KEY_HERE"];
       return YES;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem even though I did everything correctly. I made a mistake at choosing the framework. I had taken GoogleMapsM4B.framework instead of GoogleMaps.framework. I overcame this error after choosing suitable framework from [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases) link.

This might be helpful to someone.