# Using Google Maps SDK with Parse.com Project iOS Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, google-maps-sdk-ios, linker-flags

Im working on a project (xcode 6.3+, swift) using Parse SDK (parse.com) to handle data.
Recently, we decided to use the google maps sdk to provide user with directions using the direction API. As you can use this API without the google map I started integrating it. It's my first time with cocoapods so I followed the instruction and started playing with.

`pod init` to create the pod specs file

here is my config coming from google Starting Guide

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

`pod install`, then launching the project using the `.xworkspace`

I directly try to build the project and it returns 34 errors.
the type of error is always the same: `Apple Match-O Linker Error`

[image]

[image]

So I start looking at google cause I did the same thing on a blank project and everything was working really good.

I start to find information about the fact that using Parse SDK causes conflicts with the -ObjC linker Flags that GoogleMaps needs to work. most of the answers give two potential solutions:

**1. addind the Facebook-iOS-SDK framework**

tried this using the framework given by facebook, as well as using cocoapods. not working. I still got errors.

**2. Force Loading the GoogleMaps framework by replacing the -ObjC flag by the following**

```
-force_load $(PROJECT_DIR)/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework
```

this returns an error as well: 
[image]

so now Im quite lost about the way to solve this. Is there anybody that found a way to integrate GoogleMaps SDK with Parse?

**UPDATE**

I tried a different approach by injecting GoogleMaps without cocoapods. To do this I used this method: [GoogleMaps without CocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782277/googlemaps-without-cocoapods)

It seems to integrate itself properly, but the -ObjC flag remains. Using

```
-force_load $(PROJECT_DIR)/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps
```

is now responding but causing `duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64`errors.
can't seems to find a way to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I managed to find working solution both for integrating GoogleMaps Sdk and Parse with and without cocoapods. However, the use of the -ObjC flags by GoogleMaps forced me to integrate the FacebookSDK to the equation. I couldn't find a way to make this working without it

So this config is working with xcode 6.3+ and it required to use and older version of the Facebook SDK (when not using cocoapods)

**With CocoaPods**

1/. Add the Parse SDK as described on their [website](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart?#parse_data/mobile/ios/swift/existing) (existing project version)

2/. Add extra Frameworks (AdSupport, Account and Social) as well as `libstdc++.6.dylib`

3/. Open terminal to the root folder

4/. `$ pod init`

5/. open Podfile and replace content with the following:

```
use_frameworks! 
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

6/. `$ pod install` then `$ pod update`

7/. download FacebookSDK from this [link](https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=facebook-ios-sdk-current.zip)

8/. Add `FBSDKCoreKit` and `FBSDKLoginKit` Frameworks to your project

9/. build your project.

If some error occurs, you may have to delete `ParseFacebookUtils.framework` from your project and keep only `ParseFacebookUtilsV4`.

**Without CocoaPods**

So this is quite the same procedure except that instead of using pods to install GoogleMaps SDK, you will integrate it manually by using the link mentionned in the question, or by going to GoogleMaps podspecs and access the source url to download the last one.

Make sure to add GoogleMaps.framework, as well as the GoogleMaps.bundle which you can find by right-click on GoogleMaps.framework /show in finder under Resources. Drag and drop to the project and make sure it's linked to the project build settings / Copy Bundle Resources

Also, make sure to have all the required framework and libraries listed on the link provided in the question.

Add the `-ObjC` flag under Build Settings / Other Linker Flags

When it comes to integrate the FacebookSDK, I've noticed that using the latest version isn't working. Apparently, it was prepared to work with xcode 7. Do work around this, just download an older version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514962/linker-error-in-ios-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64/32519847#32519847)

Add FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit to the project and you should be good to go.
Hope that help someone cause it was a pain to make this work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this

Click on your project (targets)
Click on Build Settings
Under Framework search paths (set your framework path)
Following information for getting framework search paths

Right click on your framework folder (for ex: GoogleMaps.framework)
select Get info
copy the path from General->where and paste this path in your framework search path (path should contain in single line)
Good luck

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work either. the search path has already $(inherited) and $(PROJECT_DIR) in it. when addind the path to the google framework it has no effect, and when deleting inherited or project_dir, it doesn't find the google framework and returns another error. seems to be imported correctly already.