# "_vImageBoxConvolve_Planar8", referenced from: (anonymous namespace)::CreateBlurredImage(CGImage*, double, double) in GoogleMaps(GLWaterGroup.o)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

I got the follwoing error when trying to run a project that is using Google maps. Notice, I copy Google maps libraries manually.
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like the library you're using has a dependency on the Accelerate.framework. You should add it to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use Google maps SDK without CocoaPods, and that is why I was getting those errors. Finally, I gave up and just used CocoaPods method :-(

I dont know why Google force developers to use CocoaPods. They should gave developers the two options and let developer choose.

Comment: True,I completely agree with you - although CocoaPods and dependency managers have its benefits.. However, you are still able to add the GoogleMaps SDK without CocoaPods - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782277/googlemaps-without-cocoapods