# I would like to add GoogleMaps to my iOS project but I don't want to use CocoaPods. Is there any way to achieve that?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I want to upgrade version of google maps in my application, but i dont want to use the CocoaPods, is it possible?

Comment: why?
is the question really - "I can't get CocoaPods to work?" or is there something you need to do that can't be achieved with Pods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GoogleMaps without CocoaPods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782277/googlemaps-without-cocoapods)

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the resources inside podspec you can get it as you can see here:

[GoogleMaps without CocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782277/googlemaps-without-cocoapods)

Answer (score 1):

```
[http://vikrambahl.com/google-maps-ios-xcode-storyboards/][1]
```

[Click here](http://vikrambahl.com/google-maps-ios-xcode-storyboards/) 
    You can visit this tutorial for googleMap without pod