# iOS: Unit Tests with GoogleMaps installed via pods clang error

Tags: ios, google-maps, unit-testing, cocoapods

I'm running some Unit Tests, which work fine without GoogleMaps. However, if I install GoogleMaps through pods, I get the error :

```
pod ld: framework not found GoogleMaps for  architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I found some answers here which involve changing some build settings, but nothing is working, and mostly the questions were about the error appearing when installing GoogleMaps without pods.

Any idea how I could solve that?

Answer (score 0):

First, try to verify if you follow the process here in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#step_1_get_the_latest_version_of_xcode) about Setting up the Google Maps SDK for IOS.

By checking other issue about your problem. I found this [github issue](https://github.com/johnno1962/injectionforxcode/issues/52), you can try to check this to know what steps you can do to solve that issue.

If the problem still occurred, maybe you can try(only suggestion) to use Google Maps without using cocoapods. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782277/googlemaps-without-cocoapods) can help and explain you on how to achieve this.

Comment: I tried all this and nothing works, and would really like to use it with pods, so I'll keep looking...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Restarted Xcode a bunch of times, cleared my DerivedData and played around with changing the Host targets.

What worked for me was:

- just do the above: restart Xcode and clear your DerivedData to start on a clean slate
- `pod update`

That was it! Hope this helps your or anyone else.