# How to make universal library /9 .a file) in iOS using xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios

How to make universal Static Library ( .a file) in iOS using xCode? [iOS portfolios](http://www.solutionanalysts.com/portfolio-tag/ios)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402092/file-is-universal-3-slices-but-does-not-contain-an-armv7s-slice-error-for-st

Answer (score 0):

Follow this screenshot:

[image]

You can create a static library by creating a new Project > Cocoa Touch Static Library.

Let me know it works or not.

Thanks,

Hemang.