# XCode won't compile due to armv7s slice error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to compile an XCode solution using XCode Version 4.6 (4H127) and iOS SDK 6.1. It always throws up this error. Can anyone help plz?

```
"ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice"

"libRunalyzerAPI.a for architecture armv7s

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
```

Comment: Please refer to the answer for this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402092/file-is-universal-three-slices-but-it-does-not-contain-an-armv7-s-slice-err

Comment: Maybe your project is missing some framework or configuration? http://api.runalyzer.com