# IPhone Linker error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

```
Ld /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QRBook-ergjaygqpaefkycaehzjplsmosjq/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/QRBook/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/QRBook.build/Distribution-iphoneos/QRBook.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/QRBook normal armv7s
    cd /Users/User/Documents/source/QRBook/iphone/QRBook
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
    setenv PATH "/Volumes/Xcode 1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Volumes/Xcode 1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    "/Volumes/Xcode 1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++" -arch armv7s -isysroot "/Volumes/Xcode 1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk" -L/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QRBook-ergjaygqpaefkycaehzjplsmosjq/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/QRBook/BuildProductsPath/Distribution-iphoneos -L/Users/User/Documents/source/QRBook/iphone/QRBook -F/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QRBook-ergjaygqpaefkycaehzjplsmosjq/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/QRBook/BuildProductsPath/Distribution-iphoneos -filelist /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QRBook-ergjaygqpaefkycaehzjplsmosjq/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/QRBook/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/QRBook.build/Distribution-iphoneos/QRBook.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/QRBook.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -framework MediaPlayer -framework AudioToolbox -liconv -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia -framework SystemConfiguration -lsqlite3.0 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lZXingWidget -o /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QRBook-ergjaygqpaefkycaehzjplsmosjq/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/QRBook/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/QRBook.build/Distribution-iphoneos/QRBook.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/QRBook

ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/User/Documents/source/QRBook/iphone/QRBook/libZXingWidget.a for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How to bypass this error for libZXingWidget.a?

Comment: the libZXingWidget.a static library that you are using hasen't been built for iPhone 5. Probably download a new one from their website(if they have updated it)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402092/file-is-universal-three-slices-but-it-does-not-contain-an-armv7-s-slice-err