# file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode4.5, armv7

I'm getting following error while running in iOS6.1 with xcode 4.5. Also i `removed armv7s from the project (target) "Build Settings" / "Valid Architectures`" and set Set the `"Build Active Architecture Only" setting to YES`. I have this file inside www folder `phonegap-1.3.0.js`. But why i'm getting below error:

```
  file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/Shared/PhoneGap/Frameworks/PhoneGap.framework/PhoneGap for architecture armv7s
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12402966/1059705 You should have to take a look at this link

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using some third party library. The error reminds you to update your third party lib,which is xxx.a file in your project. If the lib is open source, putting the code in your project is strongly suggested.