# Make library support 32bit architecture and 64bit architecture ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I created a objective-c library in Xcode 6.1. It supports 64 bit architecture. I added it to an old project with 32 bit support. It is crashing and giving me an error

```
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice
```

How can i update the library to support the old project?

Comment: You can try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402092/file-is-universal-three-slices-but-it-does-not-contain-an-armv7-s-slice-err/12402966#12402966

Comment: you can just add armv7s to the library's Target->Build Settings->Architectures along with ($_ARCHS_STANDARD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just add armv7s to the library's Target->Build Settings->Architectures along with ($_ARCHS_STANDARD)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the support for any architecture armv7s from the project (target) -> Build Settings -> Valid Architectures:
Alternatively, you can set the flag for your debug configuration's

Change Build Active Architecure Only to Yes.

Hope this will work.

Comment: i want to update the library and give support to the current existing project structure.