# Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib file error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode7

After Upgrading to **xcode 7** getting below error, I tried *adding both libraries* also but it couldn't solve my issue. Tried to update pods also.

> ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) x86_64 slice: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib' for architecture x86_64

Comment: Have you add libcommonCrypto.dylib add not? because you said i triend that means you added or not found?

Comment: Yes i have added libcommonCrypto it is there.

Comment: ok check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402092/file-is-universal-three-slices-but-it-does-not-contain-an-armv7-s-slice-err

Comment: Why are you directly adding the `libcommonCrypto.dylib` instead of `Security.framework`?

Comment: @zaph, I have added Security.framework also its still same, but when i added libcommonCrypto.dylib manually i am getting"ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): "

Comment: @RushangPrajapati, i tried that solution earlier also it din work for me.

Comment: You will need to **add** more information to the question, there is mention to "pods". All that is needed to use Common Crypto is to add the Security.framework and the needed imports. If you are adding these libraries manually as well there may well be a problem. Perhaps there is a problem with the "pods".

Comment: @rohit if you using "Pods" then not open .xcodeproj  open the .xcworkspace  file form project path

Comment: @RushangPrajapati yes i know this i am working on workspace only.anyway thanks to all of you i solved this

Comment: @Rohit if you solved this then updated your answer it will help for other :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by removing libCommonCrypto.dylib,libz.dylib from project and adding security.framework, javascript.framework to the project.