# How I decode encoded string in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, decode, encode, cardreader

I am using `iMagRead` card reader library for `iOS`. When I swipe the card then I got this type of data
[image]

How do I convert this data into `real data`? I have tried this already but fail.

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:text options:0];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"decoded string %@", decodedString); // NULL
```

Comment: can you provide me the code you created for card swiper. I am facing issue with. My email is bony@corcrm.com

Comment: hi imuzahid i have just bought the card reader and got the imagread.a library but its documentation is in chinese and its in objective C. Can you please send me the english documentation you might have got and if possible the way to use it with some example. my email id is: hirav.ind@gmail.com. would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Muzahid I am trying to implement iMagRead card reader library for iOS. But getting following error:

/iMagReadSDK/Lib/libiMagRead.a, file is universal (armv7,armv7s) but does not contain the arm64 architecture: /iMagReadSDK/Lib/libiMagRead.a

Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_iMagRead
Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: I think this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402092/file-is-universal-three-slices-but-it-does-not-contain-an-armv7-s-slice-err

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
  NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//pass data which you got from swipe as parameter
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Sorry I get null. Though I get bit string then I convert into data and do as you say. But result is null.

Comment: what you get by scan ? write here in comment

Comment: What I get that are already shown in the image. I get those bit patterns as NSString.