# Compilation Error: iMagRead card reader library for iOS

Tags: ios, credit-card, magnetic-cards

I am trying to implement iMagRead card reader library for iOS. But getting following error:

> /iMagReadSDK/Lib/libiMagRead.a, file is universal (armv7,armv7s) but does not contain the arm64 architecture: /iMagReadSDK/Lib/libiMagRead.a

> Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_iMagRead

Found related: [iMagRead card reader library for iOS. When I swipe the card then I got this type of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997424/how-i-decode-encoded-string-in-ios)

Please help me to resolve this error.