# in Xcode i get the error: File is universai (2 sl�ces) but does not contain the x86_64 architecture:

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I tried to run my xcode project but i get the error `File is universai (2 sl�ces) but does not contain the x86_64 architecture:`

is there any way to fix it? this is the output, i tried searching put i didn't find a solution

```
Ld /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalonApp_v3-fzxnatqzeeldmagmhlrpcsomcyct/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb/nanopb.framework/nanopb normal x86_64 (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/mohid/Desktop/App/SalonApp_v3/Pods
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios8.0-simulator -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.4.sdk -L/Users/mohid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalonApp_v3-fzxnatqzeeldmagmhlrpcsomcyct/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb -F/Users/mohid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalonApp_v3-fzxnatqzeeldmagmhlrpcsomcyct/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb -filelist /Users/mohid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalonApp_v3-fzxnatqzeeldmagmhlrpcsomcyct/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/nanopb.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/nanopb.framework/nanopb -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/mohid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalonApp_v3-fzxnatqzeeldmagmhlrpcsomcyct/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/nanopb_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Foundation -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/mohid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalonApp_v3-fzxnatqzeeldmagmhlrpcsomcyct/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/nanopb_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/mohid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SalonApp_v3-fzxnatqzeeldmagmhlrpcsomcyct/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb/nanopb.framework/nanopb

ld: file is universai (2 sl\317ces) but does not contain the x86_64 architecture: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: are you using a 3rd party library? if so it seems that the library doesn't support x86_64 or simulators. if you need to include simulator, you can fork out the library(if possible) and rebuild it and add the missing architecture

Comment: Does Firebase and CloudKit count? however i installed them weeks back and the project seemed to worked, its only now that it has started to not build

Comment: I tried cleaning build folder, removing derived data, removing all new lines of code but nothing seems to work

Comment: have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402092/file-is-universal-three-slices-but-it-does-not-contain-an-armv7-s-slice-err

Comment: yes, sadly non of them work :(

Comment: It seems like your current build options doesn't fit with the simulator. I'd advice you to try to enable/disable `ARC` and `Bitcode` in your submodule. Here's the similar problem: https://github.com/leetal/ios-cmake/issues/2